# How to prove that this $X_0$ is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=M_n(\mathbb C)$ and $A\subseteq B$ are subspaces of $V$. Let also
$$
M=\{X\in V:\ \forall Y\in B,\ XY-YX\in A\}.
$$
Suppose $X_0\in M$ enjoys the property that $\operatorname{tr}(ZX_0)=0$ for any $Z\in M$. Show that $X_0$ is nilpotent.

---

My attempt: I know that
$$\operatorname{tr}(XY-YX)=0$$
but I cannot continue from there. Thank you for any help. The problem appears on a Chinese bulletin board. A soluton can be found in section 4.3 of James E. Humphreys, *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory*, but I want to know if this problem can be solved by other methods. Thank you.

Comment: I made some edits, please check them!

Comment: I have see this problem in china BBS,But I also not see solution, this problem is this 设V是C^n到自己的线性变换组成的空间，B是V的子空间，A是B的子空间。设M={X∈V：任Y∈B，XY-YX∈A}.设X_0∈M使得任Z∈M，有tr(ZX_0)=0.求证，X_0是幂零变换

Comment: $V:C^{n}\to C^n$

Comment: @nanchangjian how do you have that $trace(ZX_0)=0$ it seems nontrivial.  Could you state proof?

Comment: sorry, it;s such $trance(ZX_{0})=0$

Comment: Its a nice problem. See this book : Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory James E.Humphreys. section 4.3. proof is given nicely here.

Comment: Something is missing on your assumptions. If $A=B=0$ then $M$ is just equal to $V$. Take any $X\in V$ and $Z=0$, then clearly $\text{trace}(ZX)=0$, but $X$ can be arbitrary.

Comment: Something is clearly wrong with the statement. Nothing prevents taking $Z=0$, since $0\in M$ always, and for this $Z$ you get no information on $X_0$. Do you mean $\operatorname{tr}(ZX_0)=0$ for _all_ $Z\in M$?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a comment but did not have sufficient reputation points. So I put my comment here which extends that of Marc.

As $A$ contains $0$, the constant diagonal matrices $k I$ ($I$ is the identity matrix) are in $M$. So, if $tr(ZX_{0}) = 0$ for all $Z \in M$ then $tr(X_{0}) = 0$. But there are invertible matrix with zero trace.

So the statement is wrong, either $tr(ZX_{0}) = 0$ for all $Z \in M$ or $tr(ZX_{0}) = 0$ for some $Z \in M$.

Comment: Fix a traceless invertible matrix $X_0$. That $tr(ZX_0)=0$ for $Z=kI\in M$ doesn't mean $tr(ZX_0)=0$ for all $Z\in M$, so I don't see how your argument serves as a counterexample to the problem statement.